# Compare screen-width and height in CSS

Tags: css

So I've been following a tutorial on responsive website and they way they did it was by using a grid system and change that when

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 550px) {/*change style here*/}
```

Now I am not satisfied with the `(max-width: 550px)` part as most phones have a higher resolution. My idea is to check whether the screen height is greater than the screen width something like `(max-width < max-height)` but I don't know how to do it.
Thank you in advance.

Edit: I am also open for JS if necessary.

Comment: Media queries have [an orientation property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/orientation) that does this for you.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

@media only screen and (max-width: 550px) and (min-height:550px)

with JS

window.innerHeight < 550 ? alert('min') : alert('max');

Jquery

$(window).width() < 550 ? alert('min') : alert('max');

Comment: I am new to JS etc so can you please explain what ´alert('min')´ and ´alert('max')´ do or are they just placeholders?

Comment: it is just a placeholder you can put the code you want there, if the screen height is less than 550 it will make the min code, if it is higher it will make the max code but if you are starting I recommend you use if and else to practice like this:

if(window.innerHeight < 550) {code for less than 550px} else {code for greater than 550px}.

Comment: (condition) ? true code : false code;
that operator is called a ternary operator and it's the same as 
if(condition) {true code} else {false code}